# Running workflows on pull requests to a private repository?

Tags: github, github-actions, pull-request

I'm managing a small private repository with a tightly controlled list of contributors who can make pull requests against the repository. I'd like to be able to run some simple automatic validation of pull requests (syntax checks, formatting, etc).

Unfortunately, it seems like for security reasons that GitHub doesn't permit `pull_request` workflows from a fork to run in private repositories, and while `pull_request_target` workflows work, they don't have access to the contents of the pull request.

I was hoping that I could explicitly check out the pull request, since for our situation we're not worried about the security concerns referenced in e.g. [this article](https://securitylab.github.com/research/github-actions-preventing-pwn-requests/), but as far as I can tell neither the environment (`$GITHUB_*`) nor the `gitub` context (`${{ github.* }}`) provides the necessary information to make that possible.

Is there any way to trigger github workflows on pull requests in a private repository? Or is the only option some sort of external tool (e.g. something that receives webhook notifications of the pull request and uses the [checks API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/checks) to interact with the pr)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `pull_request` workflows do indeed work on private repos because I'm pretty sure we have those at work.  Maybe you want to say a few words about what you're seeing that leads you to believe they don't?

Comment: Well, e.g., the discussion [here](https://github.community/t/will-github-actions-support-pull-request-events-from-a-fork-to-a-private-base-repository/17471). I've updated the question to clarify that I'm asking about pull requests from forks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a **Fork pull request workflows** setting that needs to be turned on to allow running workflows on pull requests to a private repository:
https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/enabling-features-for-your-repository/managing-github-actions-settings-for-a-repository#enabling-workflows-for-forks-of-private-repositories

Comment: Why would the option to do that be greyed out for me?